# How can I keep Jekyll from adding whitespace in highlight?

Tags: jekyll, liquid, pygments

I'm currently experimenting with Jekyll. Most things look fine, but the way Jekyll processes code highlighting seems to be buggy.

I use pygments.

Then Jekyll seems to use pieces like:

```
{% highlight python %}
#!/usr/bin/env python

def wer(r, h):
    """
{% endhighlight %}
```

to generate code like

```
<div class="highlight">
   <pre>
      <code class="python"><span class="c">#!/usr/bin/env python</span>

<span class="k">def</span> <span class="nf">wer</span><span class="p">(</span><span class="n">r</span><span class="p">,</span> <span class="n">h</span><span class="p">):</span>
    <span class="sd">"""</span>
<span class="sd">        Calculation of WER with Levenshtein distance.</span>
<span class="sd">        Works only for iterables up to 254 elements (uint8).</span>
<span class="sd">        O(nm) time ans space complexity.</span>
[...]
    <span class="n">doctest</span><span class="o">.</span><span class="n">testmod</span><span class="p">()</span>
</code>
   </pre>
</div>
```

which looks like

[image]

[image]

The problem is whitespace between `code` and `pre`:

[image]

How can I tell Jekyll not to put whitespace between those tags?

- [repository with my blog](https://github.com/MartinThoma/MartinThoma.github.io)
- a [rendered example page](http://martinthoma.github.io/jekyll-and-git/) (with this [source page](https://raw.github.com/MartinThoma/MartinThoma.github.io/source/_posts/2013-12-09-jekyll-and-git.markdown)).

### Bug hunting

- My Jekyll version is `jekyll 1.3.1`.
- With `gem environment` I found that my gems are at `/var/lib/gems/1.9.1`.
- With `grep -rn "highlight" --exclude-dir=site --exclude-dir=test *` I found that the highlight tag gets parsed in `/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.3.1/lib/jekyll/tags/highlight.rb`
- As this might be a Jekyll bug, I've added [issue 1801](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/issues/1801)

Now comes the strange part: `highlight.rb` seems not to add any whitespace between `<pre>` and `<code>`.

Comment: I looked at your [source code](https://raw.github.com/MartinThoma/MartinThoma.github.io/source/_posts/2013-12-09-jekyll-and-git.markdown). Just out of curiosity, why are you using HTML tags inside your markdown file? Why aren't you using Markdown?

Comment: I'm currently trying to migrate from WordPress to Jekyll. So the reason is simply that I had HTML before. I'm currently not sure if I want to switch. An advantage of using HTML is that I know the syntax.

Comment: Jekyll does support HTML files. If you're going to use pure HTML in your posts, I would recommend changing your file extensions from `.markdown` to `.html`. This way your posts won't be sent through the Markdown processor.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that. As markdown might be another source for errors, I've switched to `.html` files. The problem is still there.

Comment: I also tried changing the file extension to `.html`, and that didn't fix anything. I also converted your post to markdown, and that still produced the same error. Since the spaces were added between the `<pre>` and `<code>` tags in both cases, I think it's an issue with the processor and the `{% highlight bash %}` tag.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, could you check if it can be fixed with CSS-only by using code from this article: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/make-pre-text-wrap/

Comment: CSS answers cannot work for this problem. Not every leading space is bad. Sometimes I need indentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is caused by Liquid, the templating engine of Jekyll (see [Issue 216](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/issues/216) of Liquid and [Issue 1806](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/1801) of Jekyll).

The current (12.12.2013) answer to this question is: You cannot keep Jekyll from adding those whitespaces.

But a fix to the underlying problem is to remove the whitespaces after all pages have been compiled. I've written the following Python script to do so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re, fnmatch, os

def removeWhitespace(file_path):
    #read file content
    with open(file_path) as f:
        content = f.read()

    #replace whitespace
    openingTag = re.compile('<pre>\s*<code', re.DOTALL)
    closingTag = re.compile('</code>\s*</pre>', re.DOTALL)
    if re.findall(openingTag, content):
        content = re.sub(openingTag, '<pre><code', content)
        content = re.sub(closingTag, '</code></pre>', content)

    #write without whitespace
    with open(file_path,'w') as f:
        f.write(content)

# Get all HTML files
files = []
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.'):
  for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.html'):
      files.append(os.path.join(root, filename))

for filename in files:
    removeWhitespace(filename)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is stylesheet related.

I was able to build your sample page on my test environment using the default without any problem*.

Try adding the following to `style.css`

```
/* standard */
 .post pre {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-color: #eef;
  padding: 0 .4em;
}
```

* Only problem I had was it complained about the following line

`<a href="http://jekyllrb.com/">Jekyll</a> is a static blog generator.`

Which I resolved by wrapping the line in a paragraph tag.

Comment: No, this does not fix the problem (see latest build)

Comment: OK. I will try a few more tweaks. It is definitely a CSS issue rather than a Jekyll issue though.

Comment: You can see that added whitespace is the problem when you remove whitespace betweeen `<pre>` and `<code>`. Something adds this whitespace and I think it is Jekyll. Please delete your "answer" because it did not answer my question.

Comment: I am not seeing any extraneous whitespace when I view source on the sample page. Also, as I have said the page builds without any problem on my test installation using default style.

Comment: I've added an image of the lines of code. Please take a look at it. It's definitely there.

Comment: Even if the problem of intendation was a stylesheet related (but I'm very sure it is not) I've asked how to remove the whitespace. You did not answer this question. So please delete this or answer my question.